# Mother class attribute return NULL

Tags: php, class, object, parent

I am working on a PHP Object and I have a problem, I try to call an attribute (which is an object) from a mother class, and it's null. I'll show you my problem:

```
Class A {
    protected $attribute;
    
    public function __construct() {
         $this->attribute = new C();
    }

    public function foo() {
        new B();
    }
}

Class B extends A {
     public function __construct() {
         var_dump($this->attribute) // show "NULL"
     }
}
```

Comment: It's usually called 'parent class'.

Answer (score 0):

You are overriding **A**'s constructor in **B**, which means that A's constructor never gets called, and consequently, `$attribute` never gets set. If you want to execute A's constructor in B, you need to do so explicitly:

```
class B extends A {
     public function __construct() {
         parent::__construct(); // This is required if you want to execute A's constructor
         var_dump($this->attribute);
     }
}
```